# Source of java HttpServer

Tags: java, com.sun.net.httpserver

I am unable to find com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer source in src.jar of java 1.6. 
Where is it available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.java) you will find source code for com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I already found that. But I want to be able to browse the code from IntelliJ [My Java IDE] itself. The way you do for String etc.

Comment: @Fakrudeen: You can attach single source file in IDE. Do you want sources of all files in jar?

Comment: yes they way you get for String, HashMap etc. in src.jar of java 1.6

Comment: @Fakrudeen: The link I have posted contains source of all files in jar. You can also download the sources there.

Comment: Thanks - I found the jar. But is openjdk the same as jdk [w.r.to this class]? http://repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/openjdk-6-b14-sources.jar